# Exit the app after clicking the back button

Tags: android, back-button

I have a simple game that contains three pages: `start_page`, `play_page` and `lose_page`. In the `lose_page` I added `home_button` that will take you to the `start_page` to play again.

What I want is when I press the back button of the phone in the `start_page` to take me out of the game, but the problem is the back button takes me to the previous page which is the `lose_page`.

Here is the code of the `home_button` in the `lose_page` that takes you to the `start_page`:

```
    Button home_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlayAgain);
    home_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LostActivity.this,
                    HomeActivity.class);                        
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you finish(); the lose_page when intented to to next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the finish() method to your code,

```
  Button home_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlayAgain);
    home_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LostActivity.this,
                    HomeActivity.class);                        
            startActivity(i);
            //call the finish method
            finish();

        }
    });
```

When calling finish() on an activity, the method onDestroy() is executed and will destroy your LostActivity which would prevent going back to LostActivity from HomeActivity.

Comment: thanks it worked, I also had to add the finish()  method in the play_button in start_page to make it work perfectly.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

The finish() method inside your onClick() will do the work BUT I think there is better approach to your case.

If you start lost_page from your play_page which I think is the case, after you make startActivity(LostActivityIntent); just call finish() and it will finish your play_page and open lost_page.

After that in lost_page where your home_btn onClick() callback (the listener) is, just call finish() nothing else, don't start new Intent with your home_page because its already created.

And finally when you press the back button in your home screen it will exit the whole app. Much easy and clean solution.

You should use Android Activity stack stuff to take care about the screens, don't start intents just like that.

Comment: Exactly, I was about to comment that. I believe his backstack is a little messed up thanks to `startActviity()` usages.

Comment: @Shaishav It seems to be the true :)